# I have integrated google map. but marker updated very late .i update the marker on the response of google direction api

Tags: android, google-maps

**I have integrated google map. But marker updated very late. I update the marker on the response of google direction API**

Comment: i call direction api on Location_changed method.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: if(network_enabled) { // Checking for GSM
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, MapMain.this);}

            else   if(gps_enabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, MapMain.this);
            }

            providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);

Comment: @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        bestLocation = location;
        if(!isFirstCall) {
            lastLocation=bestLocation;
//        cameraUpdate();
        }
        new connectAsyncTask().execute();
    }

Answer (score 1):

call this method from onCreate(), i hope this will help you.

```
       public void setUpMap()
{

    final LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)   getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            position = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(position)).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.emp2));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 9));

            lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {

        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```